# Issue with website not displaying content on Android 4.1 and 4.2 browsers

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

I'm having problems displaying my club's website, specifically on Android version 4.1 and 4.2's default browser:
http://www.manchesterhandballclub.co.uk/index.html

Everything loads as normal for a split second, before everything in the #maincontent div disappears, except for the Twitter and Facebook widgets on the homepage (/index.html), or the embedded Google Maps on the Training Info page (/training_info.html).

I wondered if there was maybe some sort of z-index issue on load, but there shouldn't be anything overlaying on top of the container div to my knowledge. Here's a preview of what the homepage looks like once the main div disappears:
http://tinypic.com/r/4l1zya/5

I don't have any experience designing for mobile devices, and whilst I do plan to build responsive device-friendly versions eventually, it'd be great if I could get the current site displaying as it does on all other Android versions for now. I'm not sure if there's any version-specific quirks or things I may have missed?

Thanks in advance, and apologies if I've not posted this in the correct way! Tried searching around but can't seem to find any help on the issue currently.

Comment: I'd begin by removing all the Javascript from the page and see if the problem persists. If the problem has gone, then you'll know that there is an issue with one of the chunks of script...

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately it didn't work. I've also tried taking out various other sections of the code (such as all of the header, top nav, etc) and it still isn't helping. Baffled!

Comment: If you still have the problem, even with a much smaller source, then you're on the right path. Keep removing stuff until the problem goes away, and then you'll know that the last thing you removed will have been the culprit.